# How can I completely remove the error in android coloring

Tags: android, graph-coloring

Hello: I am testing an android coloring project but there are some errors when I color in the image, the edges of the image have white jagged marks.
Please help me fix the above error, I would like to thank
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGsho.jpg)

Comment: Provide more information like, what are you using to "color" those images, are they svg, png, etc?

Comment: I tried using both .png and .jpg images but still got the same jagged marks